# Windows 8 Animation in Xaml and C# to move object from one column to another?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-8

I have made a user control to expand on click and there are 7 of them in a grid with columns. When i click on the last one it goes out of the screen. I want to animate that if it expands then it should move to grid.column 1 and then when it collapse it goes back to  its own grid.

Code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="GrdVwSearchResults" Grid.Row="2" Margin="120,70,0,0" >
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="moveBackAnimation" >
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="moveBackDoubleAnimation" EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="usrFlight5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Col" From="4" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight1" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight2" Grid.Column="1" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight3" Grid.Column="2" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight4" Grid.Column="3" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight5" Grid.Column="4" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight6" Grid.Column="5" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <usercontrol:Top3SearchResultDisplay  x:Name="usrFlight7" Grid.Column="6" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're using this, but here is an animation that would provide a "popup" look and feel to the object.

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="PopupFlight">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="usrFlight7">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <x:Int32>7</x:Int32>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="usrFlight7">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="500"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="usrFlight7">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <x:Int32>10</x:Int32>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="usrFlight7">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <x:Int32>3</x:Int32>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate changes of an element's row or column in a Grid, the best way is to use the VisualStateManager.  You can enable FluidLayout to animate layout changes such as row, grid, etc.  This can be done very easily in Expression Blend.

Here's a brief example of the XAML of a Grid with 6 columns with a button in the last column, which will animate to the first column when you click it.  For more advanced state changes you probably want to change the state in code, but this is using a behavior to change the state in XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        x:Class="TestingWPF.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
            <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup" ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.UseFluidLayout="True">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Default"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Grid.Column="5">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Expanded"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: FluidLayout is not available in Windows Store applications